# NGINX reverse proxy with Apache shows default Apache index page

Tags: server, 22.04, apache2, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a server that had Apache installed first. Subsequently I installed NGINX in order to have it reversed proxy to Apache.
According to /etc/apache2/ports.conf Apache listens to port 8090

```
Listen 8090
<IfModule ssl_module>
Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

When checking the configuration for NGINX under /etc/nginx/sites-available/default I see that the server listens to port 80. I have added five additional lines (proxy_pass and proxy_set) in order to specify the IP address and ports that NGINX and Apache are communicating:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # root /var/www/html;
        root /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://MYIPADDRESS:8090;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        }
```

I have added it to the NGINX file as shown above and in the apache folder location /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
VirtualHost *:8090>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        #DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/clients/client0/web1

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My goal is to show the index page that I have defined in another folder location here:         /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web;

Comment: Really? Nobody has a clue of what is wrong?